# WS-Security-SOAP X509PKIPathv1

Tags: wsse

I tried to connect to a soap web service using wsse security implementation.

I used nodejs client soap for processing this.

But I don't know how to generate ***value*** on example bellow.

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="mon-id">...Value...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I found several example on npmjs but all of then used #X509v3 which represent the public x509 ssl key.

I tried to found a way with open ssl to generate x509v1 but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I used #X509v3 which was the public pem of certificates.

## X509v3 is used when we have only one certificate for signing and this is my case.